# How to sort a list by my order for several times?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I have just started coding with python recently. 
I am trying to sort my list as a dictionary which I've made.
this is the dictionary:

```
X={'Si':6,'La':5,'Sol':4,'Fa':3,'Mi':2,'Re':1,'Do':0}
```

And I have a list like this:

```
A=[['Do', 'Do'], ['Re', 'Do'], ['Do', 'Mi'], ['Si', 'Do'], ['Fa', 'Fa'], ['Mi', 'Fa'], ['Sol', 'Si']]
```

I intend to sort this list into:

```
[['Do', 'Do'], ['Do', 'Mi'], ['Re', 'Do'], ['Mi', 'Fa'], ['Fa', 'Fa'], ['Sol', 'Si'], ['Si', 'Do']]
```

I mean sorting this list by sorting first element then the second element and third and ...

I have tried to fulfill this by using this code:

```
A.sort(key=lambda val: X[val[0]])
```

Therefore, I could sort the list by the first item, but for the second or third(if the inner lists contain more items) I cannot sort them.
I'm not a Groovy coder so thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by *multiple "fields"*:

```
X = {'Si':6,'La':5,'Sol':4,'Fa':3,'Mi':2,'Re':1,'Do':0}
A = [['Do', 'Do'], ['Re', 'Do'], ['Do', 'Mi'], ['Si', 'Do'], ['Fa', 'Fa'], ['Mi', 'Fa'], ['Sol', 'Si']]
result = sorted(A, key=lambda lst: tuple(X[i] for i in lst))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['Do', 'Do'], ['Do', 'Mi'], ['Re', 'Do'], ['Mi', 'Fa'], ['Fa', 'Fa'], ['Sol', 'Si'], ['Si', 'Do']]
```